# How to list all possible 3-tuples with entries of the 3 tuples from 2 different sets?

Tags: combinatorics, tuples

If there are two sets $A={1,2,3,4}$ and $B={5,6,7,8}$, how to construct list of all possible 3 tuples where the first two entries are any element from set $A$ and the 3rd entry is any element from set $B$ where repetition (for instance $(1,1,5)$) is also allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{a, b} = {Range[4], Range[5, 8]};

triples = Tuples[{a, a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, 5}, {1, 1, 6}, {1, 1, 7}, {1, 1, 8}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 7}, 
> {1, 2, 8}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 3, 8}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, 
> {1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 8}, {2, 1, 5}, {2, 1, 6}, {2, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 8}, {2, 2, 5}, 
> {2, 2, 6}, {2, 2, 7}, {2, 2, 8}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 3, 8},
> {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 1, 5}, {3, 1, 6}, {3, 1, 7},
> {3, 1, 8}, {3, 2,  5}, {3, 2, 6}, {3, 2, 7}, {3, 2, 8}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 3, 6}, 
> {3, 3,  7}, {3, 3, 8}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 1, 5},
> {4, 1, 6}, {4, 1, 7}, {4, 1, 8}, {4, 2, 5}, {4, 2, 6}, {4, 2, 7}, {4, 2, 8},
> {4, 3, 5}, {4, 3, 6}, {4, 3, 7}, {4, 3, 8}, {4, 4, 5}, {4, 4, 6}, 
> {4, 4, 7}, {4, 4, 8}}
> ```

Also

```
Flatten[Outer[List, a, a, b], 2]

% ==  triples
```

> ```
> True
> ```

and

```
Flatten[Array[{#, #2, #3} &, {4, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 5}], 2]

% ==  triples
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: (+1) In addition, if there is an `Outer` with `Flatten`, there is (usually) a  `Distribute` with none: `Distribute[{a,a,b}, List]`

Comment: This is not much of an addition to a good answer. Just a pipeline style, with even simpler function calls.`Outer[List, Range[4], Range[4], Range[5, 8]] // Flatten // 
 Partition[#, 3] &`

Comment: @PaulCommentary: Or, just for fun, (i) `Range[4]//Outer[List, #, #, 4+#]&// Flatten[#,2]&`  (ii) `Range[4]//Distribute[{#, #, 4+#},List]&`